# Multiple-line collapse in Notepad++

Tags: editor, notepad++, edit, text-manipulation

I want to use `notepad++`  to do multiple-line collapse. What I mean is that I am looking for a simple operation to turn

```
1
2
3
4
```

into

```
1 2
3 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)\R(.+)(\R)`
- replace with: `$1 $2$3`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Where `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.

This will replace a linebreak between 2 lines by these 2 lines separated by a space.